# How to read a value from the specific XML-element if xml doesn't contain white space?

Tags: xml, vb.net, web-services

Please help! How to get the specific value from xml using vb.net? This is my code:

```html
<!-- if version [lt 3.0] [gt 5.0] -->
<RESPON><CoCoKms_Tes><JUMLAH>27</JUMLAH><REF_NO><RN>KNTS1610000245</RN><RN>201612090001</RN><RN>201611300003</RN><RN>201611300003</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612050004</RN><RN>201612050004</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201612050004</RN><RN>201612070005</RN><RN>201611300003</RN><RN>201611300002</RN><RN>201611300003</RN><RN>201611300003</RN><RN>201612090001</RN><RN>201611300002</RN></REF_NO></CoCoKms_Tes></RESPON>

While xReader.Read()
                Select Case xReader.NodeType
                    Case XmlNodeType.Element
                        TextBox1.Text = ("<" + xReader.Name & ">")
                        Exit Select
                    Case XmlNodeType.Text
                        TextBox2.Text = (xReader.Value)
                        Exit Select
                End Select
            End While
<!-- end version if -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1

    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim response As XElement = doc.FirstNode

        Dim test As XElement = response.FirstNode
        Dim testName As String = test.Name.LocalName

        Dim patientName As String = CType(test.FirstNode, XElement).Name.LocalName
        Dim age As Integer = CType(test.FirstNode, XElement)

        Dim rns As List(Of String) = test.Descendants("RN").Select(Function(x) CType(x, String)).ToList()

    End Sub

End Module
```